# Can I operate on Linux kernel modules / devices from within a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, module, network-programming, driver

There is very scarce information about this.
What would be authoritative sources on whether I can do things like `depmod`, `insmod`, `rmmod` and `modprobe` from within a docker container?

This assumes the container is running the exact same Linux (kernel wise of course it is, but also when building modules the kernel headers are exactly those of the loaded kernel).

My container needs devices to be accessible and I've played around with `docker run --privileged` and `--device`, `mknod` from the container and few other operations don't complain, I can see in journalctl that stuff is happening but I'd like to make sure this isn't the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (*).

Docker has two major design goals here that get in your way:

1. A container can run largely independently of its host system; you can run an Alpine container with musl libc on a Fedora host with GNU libc.  But kernel modules are extremely specific to the exact kernel they've been compiled for.  If a routine host-system update added a vendor patch to the kernel, it would break your image.
2. Containers shouldn't be able to access things outside their own container without being explicitly granted the privilege to.  A kernel module can bypass *everything* -- filesystem permissions, container boundaries, user IDs -- and so a container typically isn't allowed to run `insmod` and similar commands, even if the container process is running as root.

If your process needs access to host devices, and loads custom kernel modules, and in general isn't compatible with Docker's isolation system, then it's better to run it directly on the host and not in a container.

(*) ...well, you *can*, if at startup time you bind-mount kernel headers from the host and build a module for the currently-running kernel, and if the container is running `--privileged`.  (You may only need `--cap-add SYS_MODULE`.)  But this path is a lot more complex, and not any more secure, than just running a host root process.

Comment: Thanks. The goal at this point is not isolation, or security, with modules we are past that. But I would still benefit from the convenience docker offers - for a container to download and build a module tarball, and install it (at build time) and then at run-time, for the duration of the container, to insert a module into the kernel. I realise this is as insecure as doing it on the host, and has limited portability, but still has some convenience.

Comment: Please add some pointers for the "this path is a lot more complex" and I'll accept the answer

Comment: It is pretty much everything I say in that last paragraph: you need the kernel headers from the _exact_ kernel running on the host, which might not be in a standard Linux distribution repository; since it could be a different kernel every time the container runs you're all but forced to compile the kernel at container startup time and not before; the image must contain a full C toolchain; you need elevated privileges far above and beyond what a container would normally be allowed.  "You can't" should be the casual Googler's take-away.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do this to some extent but not all the way. I can load the module from within the container (it loads on the host) and I can see `/dev/smth` devices on the host but not in the container - docker doesn't automatically update the contents of `/dev` at run time. A workaround is to mount the `/dev` in the container, which seems to work.